# Getting null when trying to get an auto-generated id from entity which is got by findByVariable method using JPARepository

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have this model:

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`user`")
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String phone;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return new Long(id).hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof User)) {
            return false;
        }
        return this.id == ((User) obj).getId();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    (...other getters and setters...)

}
```

This piece of code in my controller:

**UserController.java**

```
(...)

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/updatePhone", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String updatePhone(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("userForm", userService.findByUsername("testUsername"));
    return "user/updatePhone";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/updatePhone", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updatePhone(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    userService.updatePhone(userForm);
    return "redirect:/user/view";
}

(...)
```

And this in my service:

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    (...)

    @Override
    public void updatePhone(User user) {
        User entity = userRepository.findById(user.getId());
        if (entity != null) {
            entity.setPhone(user.getPhone());
        }
    }

    (...)

}
```

My problem is that when I try to get the id from the user object in the UserServiceImpl class, I am getting a null. Do you know what I must do in order to get the id properly setted in my user object? Probably it's a problem with the method findByUsername(...) of the userRepository class which returns the object without the id (which is prelude by @Id and @GeneratedValue(...) annotations in my model).

Comment: Does the form have the id in it?

Comment: @JalalSordo: I don't fully understand your question. Did you mean the language on which it's working? Generally in my application I'm using JPA Repositories in a similar way to create/update/remove records in the database and everything works. I've the problem with that concrete case.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: I don't use the id in the form - I've only one input in my form which is intended to change the phone variable.

Comment: I'm sure the complete user including the id is coming back with the user on GET right? What comes back on POST?

Comment: I had a similiar issue with sqlserver2008, try GenerationType.IDENTITY.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: Maybe I'll describe it in the other words. When I use the findById(...) method, I am getting an user object which is exactly the same as in the database. The problem is with that I don't have the id property (I've null) in the user object when using the findByUsername(...) method. So I don't have the id property even in GET.

Comment: @JalalSordo: I've already tried it - unfortunately it isn't working for me.

Comment: You get null for id in which part of your code ? Repo, Rest,Service ?

Comment: if you could post your `Repository` interface as well , and also when you insert the values in the DB , do they take a proper generated ID ?

Comment: Finally I solved my problem. The reason for the problem was that I thought I am getting a whole user entity with only a phone property changed while I have only this property in my POST form. In fact I am getting a "clean" user entity with only a phone setted. Solution working for me is that I additionaly set an id of a logged user in my controller when resolving request.